# How to index Prototype objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So last I tried to index a prototype object (e.g: `String.prototype`) using a `for...in` statement I was able to get all its methods and properties.

But now I seem to be unable to index the prototype as I`ve tried recently.

```
let stringProto = String.prototype;
for (let i in stringProto)
    console.log(i) // code not running, why? :'(
```

I've checked if the prototype is iterable using `Symbol.iterator` and it is but it still does not index its properties.

**GOAL**

I want to be able to index each method/ property of a prototype object in JavaScript (I`m going to back them up in a separate **private** object).

**REASON**:

- It's for a JavaScript library I`m working on: https://github.com/LapysDev/LapysJS.
- Useful for preventing edge-cases like this: `String.prototype.replace = null` from getting in the way of running your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built-in prototype methods aren't iterable (see the spec).

Instead, use `getOwnPropertyNames()`.